# Access 'this' variables with string index

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm on a vue3 app using typeScript.

In a component, I want to access the content of 'this' variables with a variable.
For exemple, I have :
this.signIn
this.signOut,

I have the following function :

```
toggleDialog: function (dialogName: string, state: boolean | undefined) {
      
      if (!(dialogName in this)) {
        console.error('dialogName is invalid: ', dialogName);
        return;
      }
      if (state != undefined) {
        this[dialogName] = state;
      } else {
        this[dialogName] = !this[dialogName];
      }
    }
```

When I save my code, it produces me the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{ [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }, { axios: AxiosInstance; isTimerTokenOn: Ref<boolean>; ... 16 more ...; clientId: string; }, ... 15 more ..., {}>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{ [x: string & `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: string & `on${string}`]: undefined; }, { axios: AxiosInstance; isTimerTokenOn: Ref<boolean>; ... 16 more ...; clientId: string; }, ... 15 more ..., {}>'.
```

I tried something like this :

```
this[dialogName as keyof CreateComponentPublicInstance] = state;
```

It does not works either and it produces the same error than above.

**How may I access the content of 'this' variables with a variable?**

Thank you all for your time

Comment: Try add `typeof` to your code `this[dialogName as keyof typeof CreateComponentPublicInstance] = state;`

Comment: It does not works unfortunately. It produces the same error..


On the other hands, I managed to bypass the problem by entirely rewrite the component using composition API.

Thank you anyway @QuốcCường